# Subscribe to iCloud calendar on Google

Tags: google-calendar-api, icloud

I am trying to subscribe to an iCloud calendar on my Google calendar.  I am really open to any methods, but here is the one that seems most likely to work.  [See instructions to build proxy calendar.](http://www.geek-tips.com/2013/09/05/adding-icloud-calendar-subscriptions-to-google-calendar/)  The problems is that when I try to subscribe to this proxy calendar (using both webdav://... and _http://...), I get the error message "Settings Error--Could not fetch the url."  I know the file should work because I was able to use it in Outlook.  Any idea on how to fix this, or a completely different alternative that I have not found?

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem fixed itself the next day.  I assume this is because Google cached the error and was not going to bother fetching the calendar again.  So I guess this was a non-issue.